# nltk dispersion_plot() function not working. Has the line-style "|" been removed from matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, nltk, nltk-book

I am trying to draw lexical dispersion plots using nltk dispersion_plot() function. My code is

```
from nltk.book import *
text4.dispersion_plot(["freedom","citizens"])
```

The resulting plot I get is

[image: ]([![points not lotted]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHLnq.png))

After doing some google search and going through the code of dispersion_plot() function (https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/draw/dispersion.html), I found that it uses "b|" as its line style in plot() function. But as per matplotlib documentation there are only four line styles possible {'-', '--', '-.', ':'} (https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/line_styles_reference.html).

So my doubt is whether line-style "|" was there earlier but has been removed now  because of which dispersion_plot() is unable to draw plots or is there some other reason.

And also what is the workaround for this problem?

Comment: `"b|"` means "blue vertical marker". E.g. `plt.plot([1,2,4], "b|")` will look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/domOA.png). So there is no error from this part. To find out why your code does not give the desired result you would need to show a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with my dispersion_plot (the problem appeared when I ran Jupyter on Google Collaboratory).

This cleared it up:

plt.style.use('default')